# How to add a specific item as the last item of listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a ListView control which is bound to a ObservableCollection, I want to add a specific button at the end of the last item, so that when user click the button, clear up the colltions, then hide the button. Also, if the collection is empty, don't like the button display. After searching, I found many solutions on how to change the last item's style, but in my scenario, the button isn't the element of the ItemsSource. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the button to the template so it appears on every element in the ListView. Then use a trigger to show/hide the button based on whether the item is the last item in the list.

One way to do this is to expose the last item in your list via a property on your ViewModel. The trigger should compare the DataContext of the template, which is the current item, against the LastItem. Success should set the visibility of the button.

I hope this helps.